# Computer stopped booting

Tags: boot, grub2, 16.04

A week ago my computer was running fine, I shut it down for the night and the next day it booted into grub rescue. I Followed tutorials to fix it but nothing worked, so I did a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04, and a day later it did it again.

Why is this happening if I'm not doing anything to cause it?

**Specs:** mid 2010 MBP, booting just Ubuntu 16.04

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ df
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev             3941256       0   3941256   0% /dev
tmpfs             791180    9768    781412   2% /run
/dev/sdb         1477840 1477840         0 100% /cdrom
/dev/loop0       1425792 1425792         0 100% /rofs
/cow             3955888   18952   3936936   1% /
tmpfs            3955888     220   3955668   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs               5120       4      5116   1% /run/lock
tmpfs            3955888       0   3955888   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs            3955888     132   3955756   1% /tmp
tmpfs             791180      68    791112   1% /run/user/999
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/ram0: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram1: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram2: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram3: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram4: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram5: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram6: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram7: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram8: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram9: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram10: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram11: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram12: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram13: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram14: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram15: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/loop0: 1.4 GiB, 1459982336 bytes, 2851528 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 232.9 GiB, 250059350016 bytes, 488397168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 5AF97ECF-85DB-41E9-B2AC-F27F31D3AAAD

Device         Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048   1050623   1048576   512M EFI System
/dev/sda2    1050624 472152063 471101440 224.7G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3  472152064 488396799  16244736   7.8G Linux swap




Disk /dev/sdb: 14.9 GiB, 16008609792 bytes, 31266816 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x40a863e7

Device     Boot   Start     End Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *          0 2955679 2955680  1.4G  0 Empty
/dev/sdb2       2927216 2931951    4736  2.3M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$
```

[image: gparted]

Used boot-repair, it finished and said it had an error and gave me this URl
http://paste2.org/xXBEvzfx

Comment: In terminal, do these commands, `df` and `sudo fdisk -l` (lower case L), and edit your question to include the results. Also post a screenshot of `gparted` view of your hard disk. Cheers, Al

Comment: I can't access terminal, I'm stuck at grub rescue. The prefix/root=(hd0,gpt5)/boot/grub but when I type ls that gpt5 portion doesn't exist , I've tried using all the portions are they either say no filesystem or it lists a file and says it couldn't be found

Comment: Boot the Ubuntu Live DVD, and get the gparted screenshot from there. In terminal, try the `df` and `sudo fdisk -l` commands. Edit your answer with the results. ps: Were you dual-booting with Windows 10? Cheers, Al

Comment: Any way to do it with a live USB or anything on a USB. I have my roommates computer to use as well

Comment: Yes u can do it with live USB too

Comment: I'll put my next comment in an answer so I can format it. See below. Al

Comment: I almost missed that you have posted your boot-repair info. You need to post a comment addressed to me by starting it with @heynnema. Anyway, when you installed Ubuntu, did you try and copy the Ubuntu .iso to sdb? Both sda and sdb are strange. Somehow you must be installing it wrong. Do this... *(I assume you have no data on sda)* boot the Ubuntu Live DVD. Using gparted, lay down fresh gpt partition tables on BOTH sda and sdb **(effectively wiping them out)**. Then double-click the **Install Ubuntu** icon and reinstall Ubuntu (erase & install) on sda. *(We'll worry about sdb later)*.

Comment: @heynnema my sdb is the USB live , sda is my main HDD

Comment: ah, ok. My bad about sdb. Using gparted, lay down a fresh gpt partition table on sda (effectively wiping it out), and then reinstall Ubuntu. I don't see any reason for the troubles that you're having, so best to start over one more time. Cheers, Al

Comment: @heynnema It wasnt working so i scappred the whole thing and installed mac osx again, working well so far. You were the most helpful so ill make your comments answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments...

Boot to the Ubuntu Live DVD or USB. In terminal, enter the following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && (boot-repair &)
```

or, if this is easier for you to type:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair
boot-repair
```

Lets see if boot-repair can solve your booting/grub rescue problem.

Cheers, Al